# Encoding Hebrew Text for HTML e-mail body Error

Tags: java, email, exception, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I've developed a program that eventually sends an e-mail of confirmation.
I need the Email to be sent in Hebrew.
so, I first tried to send the body text in plain text, it was fine, but in order to align the text RIGHT-TO-LEFT, I have to format it as HTML.

First I used:

```
    mbp1.setContent(new String(message.getBytes("UTF8"),"ISO-8859-1"), "text/html");
```

**the Western European" character set, it worked fine in MS outlook, but Gmail gave me gibberish.**

Then I changed it to:

```
    mbp1.setContent(new String(message.getBytes("UTF8"),"ISO-8859-8-i"), "text/html");
```

**which now works perfect !!!**
**only that I get a weird error message from java every time i send an e-mail:**

```
     java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: ISO-8859-8-E
 at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at GoogleMail.Send(GoogleMail.java:78)
 at GoogleMail.Send(GoogleMail.java:31)
 at MainFrame.sendButtonActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:596)
 at MainFrame.access$3(MainFrame.java:563)
 at MainFrame$3.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:423)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**everything now works fine, and the error is not aborting my app, but it pisses me off to have an error like this when I don't know its roots.**

**UPDATE**
16.09.2014 12:34

I have just compiled my app to a jar file, and when I run it on Win7 with the ISO-8859-8-I encoding I get gibrish in outlook and gmail !!!

**it only worked fine inside eclipse !**

I have to try setting it back to ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-8.
will update !

Please Help !!!

10x

Dave.

**UPDATE 2**
16.09.2014 13:18

I tried to use your JCharset as [stacky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4017037/stacky) suggested in order to use ISO-8859-I without an error.
it did fix the eclipse error but screwed everything else.
Now I use the ISO-8859-1 charset.

When I receive the message on outlook its perfect:
מק"ט: 19
התקבל ב: 2014-09-16
בשעה: 13:00:24
שם הפרוייקט: 
שם מזמין העבודה:

BUT, When I receive the message on Gmail, it’s all scrambled:
×ž×§"×˜: 19
×”×ª×§×‘×œ ×‘: 2014-09-16
×‘×©×¢×”: 13:00:24
×©× ×”×¤×¨×•×™×™×§×˜: 
×©× ×ž×–×ž×™×Ÿ ×”×¢×‘×•×“×”:

I tried to play with the browsers encoding settings, but no such luck, 
It's now set to Unicode-UTF 8

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the characters you're trying to send are defined by the Unicode standard (aren't they all?), and you've correctly created a Java String object containing those Unicode characters, you should be able to send them using the utf-8 encoding.  Of course, that depends on the mail reader understanding utf-8 (most all do these days) and being able to display these particular Unicode characters (which might require special fonts or language packs to be installed on the client machine).

However, I don't know how the right-to-left display issues are supposed to be handled.  Is that implicit in the display of strings of certain Unicode characters?

Code such as new String(message.getBytes("UTF8"),"ISO-8859-1") should never be necessary.  If "message" contains the correct Unicode characters, you should be able to use mbp1.setText(message, "utf-8", "html").  If "message" doesn't contain the correct Unicode characters, e.g., because you've read it from a file using the incorrect character encoding, you need to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Sun/Oracle's JRE installs converters based on the target OS's configuration. If the Windows only has European languages, only a subset of supported encodings are installed. For more detail, please take a look at this:

For Java 6
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

For Java 7
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Your first code seems correct :

Example for email in hebrew

```
 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

 BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
 htmlPart.setContent(new String(messageHtml.getBytes("UTF8"),"ISO-8859-1"), "text/html");
 multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

 message.setContent(multipart);
 message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
 message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
```

The trick is to convert the html from UTF-8 (the way it came from my message_iw.properties), and then transform it into ISO format, so that there's no need to set any headers.

Comment: that's exactly what I did, and the "ISO-8859-1" works fine when I open my mail on outlook, but on gmail its all scrambled. I tried all typed of encoding that I could find, and only the "ISO-8859-8-i" did the job right. that's what's bugging me so much :)  what exactly is the "ISO-8859-8-i" encoding ?  I didnt looked at the links you gave me yet, but I will , soon.  10x

Comment: I just saw your link with the supported encodings, the weird thing is that the ISO-8859-8-i is the only one that works, and its not even supported by java. I don't understand why !?!

Comment: Use this : http://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/

"The ISO 8859-8 charset implementation exists in the standard 
JRE. However, it is lacking the i/e aliases, which specify whether bidirectionality is implicit or explicit. The charsets conversions themselves are similar. This charset complements the standard one."

Comment: BTW , what did you mean by "message_iw.properties"

Comment: It's a property file for custom message.

Comment: I have tried using the "JCharset", it did fix the error, but now im back on gibberish. I got back to ISO-8859-1 , and now I see all good in out look, and gibberish in Gmail, I probably did not get you correctly with "The trick is to convert the html from UTF-8....."  can you please post an example, because the code example you posted is much similar to my current code.  thank you very much for your time and help, I'm getting crazy here :) , also , I tried playing with the browser encoding settings, tried everything without luck, it was and remained Unicode-UTF8.

Comment: I have find this, I thinks Elliotte Rusty Harold can resolve your issue  : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/ISO88598ASCIIplusHebrew.htm

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work !

the code I used :

```
// -- Create a new message --
final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

// -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail, false));

if (ccEmail.length() > 0) {
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail, false));
}

msg.setSubject(title, "utf-8");
msg.setText(message, "utf-8");
msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
msg.setSentDate(new Date());

MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
  try {
mbp1.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
new ByteArrayDataSource(message.toString(), "text/html")));
      } catch (IOException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
  }
 mbp1.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\""); 
 mbp1.setContent( message, "text/html; charset=utf-8" ); 
 mbp1.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable");

// create the second message part
MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();

// attach the file to the message
try {
mbp2.attachFile(fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);
msg.setContent(mp, "text/html");
```